# Integrate Boostrap Ib Bigcommerce stencil theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, themes, bigcommerce

I am new to bigcommerce stencil theme. 
Any one have any idea about how to integrate bootstrap in stencil theme for local development. is it possible to integrate custom css and js to stencil theme ?

Comment: Just learn foundation. The amount of effort this would take is not worth it.

Comment: Please [don't ask the same question twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817237/bigcommerce-stencil-theme-devlopment-on-local-machine-using-boostrap-html) and expect a different answer. Edit the existing question to improve/clarify it. Explain what specific problems/issues there are.

Comment: i would like to build stencil theme using bootstrap. i have install `npm install bootstrap-loader bootstrap-sass url-loader imports-loader --save-dev` but stencil start command give lots of errors

Answer (score 1):

This is frankly pretty complex but the starting direction you should work with is to remove @bigcommerce/citadel and foundation-sites packages. Delete ./assets/scss directory if you are willing to rewrite rather than refactor existing scss. Refactoring would be necessary due to dependence on Citadel.

You'll need to install some dependencies to work with bootstrap in conjunction with webpack.

`npm install bootstrap-loader bootstrap-sass url-loader imports-loader --save-dev`

- [bootstrap-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-loader)
- [bootstrap-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-sass)
- [url-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-loader)
- [imports-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imports-loader)

For bootstrap to use jquery and to allow babel to polyfill stencil-utils and the asset directory, you will need to modify the webpack.config.js file.

You may also want configuration option which [bootstrap-loader can provide](https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader#usage) and you'll need to ensure dependencies are properly imported to .js files.

You can get some partial details here: https://medium.com/@victorleungtw/how-to-use-webpack-with-react-and-bootstrap-b94d33765970#.85qo3a7dr

Comment: I am install bootstrap in conjuction with webpack. 
`npm install bootstrap-loader bootstrap-sass url-loader imports-loader --save-dev`.
but when I am run stencil start -e command its give errors. I have no any idea where and which changes required to change in wepack.config.js file. Please explain and help me in detail if you have done before that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to storefront > Footer scripts and add your bootstrap script there. It will work fine.